# Repairing 11 years old HDD - dynamic disc

Tags: dynamic-disk

I would ask you is possible at home repair and read data from disc Seagate ST31000528AS which was not used for almost 11 years. I found this disc at home so I connect it to notebook via USB adapter. The disc is running (spinning) and in windows 10 is shown the name of the disc "ST3110005 28AS USB Device" and in the disc management is shown that the disc is "dynamic" and "invalid". I think that I used this HDD  for data and then I had second HDD with operating system in my PC setup. I do not have any backups of these disc. Do you think that is possible repair and read data from this "dynamic" and "invalid" disc at home?

[picture from disc shown in windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw1DN.png)

Thank you for help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk. you could try to turn it back into a basic disk.

Comment: Hello, turning into basic disc will erase all data. This is not what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have the basic disk this dynamic disk was tied to (and that seems likely based on your post, then:

(1) you have lost the data.

(2) all you can do is format it and see if that repairs it,

This is a basic characteristic of dynamic disks.  I had a dynamic disk some years back and had to tie it to the owner disk to retrieve the data